# How to use a variable from a file in a COPY command in Docker?

Tags: docker

I have a multi-stage build, one to build the Angular project, and an nginx stage that should copy the contents from the Angular build to its own container.

In the Angular build stage, I output the project name and project version to a file `project.env` and copy that over to the nginx container in the second stage. Now I want to read the `project.env` file, extract the `PROJECT_NAME` key and use that in a `COPY` command. How can I solve this? This is what I have now

```
FROM node:16-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci    
RUN echo "PROJECT_NAME=`npm pkg get name`" >> /tmp/project.env
RUN echo "PROJECT_VERSION=`npm pkg get version`" >> /tmp/project.env    
COPY . .
RUN npm run build --omit-dev

FROM nginx:1.23.4-alpine
COPY --from=build /tmp/project.env /tmp/project.env
RUN export PROJECT_NAME=$(source /tmp/project.env && echo $PROJECT_NAME)
COPY --from=build /app/dist/$PROJECT_NAME /usr/share/nginx/html # < THIS DOES NOT WORK
EXPOSE 80 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Maybe there is a better way as well. Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This specific path won't work as you've described it.  It is possible to put the [environment variable reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) in `COPY`, but it's not possible to dynamically set the environment variable in a previous `ENV` instruction.

It is possible to dynamically set a variable in a `RUN` command, but like other environment variables it will disappear at the end of the `RUN` command.  Still, you can use this in the first stage to move the build directory to a place with a fixed name:

```bash
FROM node:16-alpine as build
# ... actually do the build ...
RUN mv dist/$(npm pkg get name) /dist
# RUN . /tmp/project.env && mv dist/$PROJECT_NAME /dist

FROM nginx:1.23.4-alpine
COPY --from=build /dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```